# Should the names of methods, processes or roles be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization

A question concerning capitalisation to calrify ambiguity as I've seen the words variously capitalized.

Should the names of methods, processes or roles be capitalized? ( f. ex. Agile method, Sprint Backlog ...) 
If so, do both words in a two-word noun have to  be capitalized? ( f. ex. Scrum Master).

Thanks a lot for the reply!

Comment: Not unless it is part of a company's style sheet or patented.

Answer (score 1):

This is a style question rather than a grammar or mechanics question. If, in using these terms, you make them into proper nouns (that is, they become the "official" name of something) then you can use capitals -- but I don't believe it's really necessary. And yes, if you make them into proper nouns, capitalize both words.